# Error while rendering EJS file, browser not recognizing local JSON properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

this is my ejs code:

```
<h1>Welcome to website</h1>
<%-include('post')%>
<%=posts%>
```

this is my action/controller function:

```
module.exports.postpost = (req,res)=>{
postschema.create({
    content:req.body.content,
    user:req.user._id
},(err,doc)=>{
    if(err)console.log(err);
    console.log(doc);
});
postschema.find({},(err,doc)=>{
    if(err)console.log(err);
    console.log(doc);
    let mydata = {
        posts:doc
    }
    return res.render("user_profile",mydata);
});
```

}

this is the error im getting:

> eReferenceError: /Users/aman/Documents/Web development /projects/relating database/views/user_profile.ejs:3

```
1| <h1>Welcome to website</h1>
2| <%-include('post')%>
3| <%=posts%>
```

posts is not defined
at eval (eval at compile (/Users/aman/Documents/Web development /projects/relating database/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12), :15:25)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your templating engine as Ejs in `app.js`.
You may also define your views directory in the `app.js`.

Hope it works for you...

Comment: Yes i did it but it still doesnt work